# Prevent Visual Studio from highlighting similar words

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

If I highlight a variable named "abc", and I also have a method named "abc1", the `abc` in `abc1` get lightly-highlighted.

[image]

I tried preventing that by unchecking `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Highlighting > Highlight related keywords under cursor` [what does that even mean?] but to no avail.

*Is* there a way to prevent that?

(VS version 17.4.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Selection Match Highlighting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-4/#selection-match-highlighting) feature.

> The selection match highlighting is a new feature to help you quickly
> find additional occurrences of a string in the document you’re
> editing.
>
> When it’s checked, any time you select something in your editor, anywhere else that exact string occurs will be subtly highlighted both in the editor and in the scrollbar.

To disable, uncheck the "Show selection matches" checkbox

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Show selection matches
```

[image]